# problem with selecting a rows in advanced datagrid using keydown event

Tags: flex3

I have advanced datagrid with list of items is displayed.I am using keydown  for selecting the rows.But the actual problem is when i am selecting the items after the 2nd item it should move to the 3rd item but instead of that its moving back to the 1st item.I have defined selectionmode property to singlerows even then the result same to be same.can any one give me the soloution.

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved this issue..it was related to binding problem what we had in datgrid.